# Can I ask for someone to post some photos from a camera?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, questions, images

Can I ask someone to post some images from a particular camera without getting the question down-voted?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good Stack Exchange question — in fact, it's not really a question at all, but a *service request*. You're asking for someone to make a photograph for you, or to Google up some results.

There are review sites that do the former, and *you* can do the latter just as well as we could.

I do want to add, though, that peering at sample photos is only going to tell you a small part of the "differences in quality" between modern cameras. All cameras today are capable of producing stunning, top-quality images, when used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the question.  The first step is to make sure the question itself is a good fit for this site.

Then there has to be a good reason why the many pictures out there of various cameras aren't good enough already.  The obvious place to look for pictures of a camera is on the manufacturer's site where they are trying to explain how wonderful the camera is.

If your question truly needs a specific picture of a specific camera that is not reasonably out there already, then go ahead and ask.  This is of course, again, assuming the question belongs here in the first place.  Note that the more obscure the camera, the less likely someone will be able to provide a picture of it.

Comment: Actually I want to see the differences in quality of two cameras.

Comment: I feel that you're ether going to be talking about a relatively common camera, in which case DPReview probably solves your issue, or obscure cameras, in which case you're going to need someone prepared to take identical shots with obscure cameras, which seems fairly unlikely. Exactly which cameras are you thinking about?

Comment: @phil: You seem to have misunderstood.  I'm not the one asking the question or looking for pictures of cameras.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I haven't misunderstood. I may just not have made it very clear my comment was addressed to the OP :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I don't want two specific models. I want a full frame and a medium format.

Answer (score 1):

As is always the case, there is no guarantee your question won't get downvoted. But, good questions *rarely* get downvoted. Generally, I think that the voters here tend towards generosity rather than punishment when it comes to voting on questions.